# How to compare prefix of memo field to short text field in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access

With postgresql and using a front end of MS Access.
I have a memo field named "tagNumber" for rfid tag numbers in inventoryTable. (e.g. CCE1D0010000000019030101)
I want to link the first eight characters (e.g. CCE1D001) to a groupName table to grab the type of item it is.  The groupName table would be cols of "prefix" and "name" in "itemNameTable".
Linking the first eight characters of the tagNumber to the prefix col of the "itemNameTable".

I have made a query to do this and get an error "cannot join memo....."
I have tried to sort out the first eight characters in a query and then compare that query to the prefix and get the same error.

This query gets the last time an item is inventoried through a portal

```
SELECT transactions.encoded_value,
max(transactions.created_at) AS maxofcreated_at,
"left"(transactions.encoded_value::character(8)::text, 8) AS prefix
FROM transactions
GROUP BY transactions.encoded_value;
```

Then when I use this and link "prefix" to itemNameTable I get an error "cannot join memo....."

Comment: Not really clear what this is about but `left()` and some sort of `JOIN` (maybe `LEFT JOIN`) could be involved. Look them up.

Comment: sorry I wasn't quite done posting, I have edited it

Comment: Edit question to show attempted query SQL statement.

Comment: I have edited and added query

Comment: Why are you using quote marks around Left function?

Comment: That is copied from properties of the view in PG